# Differentiation on whether directory exists and permission error

Tags: linux, bash

Looking for a very simple way to check whether a file/directory exists while evaluating user permissions, returning different (code) errors:

There is command `test` that checks for permissions but fails to provide a better return code for case where file does not exist:

```sh
$ test -r /tmp/; echo $?           # 0
$ test -r /tmp/root/; echo $?      # 1
$ test -r /tmp/missing/; echo $?   # 1
```

I am looking for something similar to `ls` where I get a different message for different errors:

```sh
$ ls /tmp/root
ls: root: Permission denied
$ ls /tmp/missing
ls: /tmp/missing: No such file or directory
```

I like the differentiation but the error code is `1` in both. To properly handle each error, I have to parse `stderr` which is honestly a very inelegant solution.

Isn't there a better and graceful way of doing this?

---

Something close to a `pythonic` way looks something like this:

```py
import os

os.listdir("/tmp/root/dir/")  # raises PermissionError
os.listdir("/tmp/foo/")       # raises FileNotFoundError
```

Comment: [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)

Comment: Use `-e` to test whether it exists, and `-r` to test whether it's readable.

Comment: @dawg looked into that one . Perhaps an example worth sharing ?

Comment: @Barmar -e and -r will both fail for /tmp/root/dir/

Comment: Note well that there is a difference between `ls` on a directory or a symlink to one, and `ls` on any other file. The former fails if the directory does not exist, if it is not readable, or if it is nonempty and not traversible.  The latter fails only if the file does not exist.  Is it only the behavior for directories in which you are interested?

Comment: Also, yes, a file that does not exist (or cannot be determined to exist) also is not readable. Conversely, if **D** is a directory that you do not have permission to read, then you cannot distinguish between paths through **D** that do not exist and those that do, but which you just cannot access.

Comment: Overall, I think it would help focus your answers if you explained your (or at least *a*) use case for your script differentiating between the different situations.  User messaging does not cut it, because in most cases, one would just attempt the desired access, and let the tool used report on the nature of any failure.

Answer (score 1):

The shell and standard utilities do not provide a command that does everything you seem to want:

- with a single command execution,
- terminate with an exit status that reports in detail on the existence and accessability of a given path,
- contextualized for the current user,
- accurately even in the event that a directory prior to the last path element is untraversable (*note: you cannot have this one no matter what*),
- (maybe) correctly for both directories and regular files.

The Python `os.listdir()` doesn't do all of that either, even if you exclude the applicability to regular files and traversing untraversible directories, and reinterpret what "exit status" means.  However, `os.listdir()` and `ls` both do demonstrate a good and useful pattern: to attempt a desired operation and deal with any failure that results, instead of trying to predict what *would* happen if you tried it.

Moreover, it's unclear why you want what you say you want.  The main reason I can think of for wanting information about the reason for a file-access failure is user messaging, but in most cases you get that for free by just trying to perform the wanted access.  If you take that out of the picture, then it rarely matters *why* a given path is inaccessible.  Any way around, you need to either switch to an alternative or fail.

If you nevertheless really do want something that does as much as possible of the above, then you probably will have to roll your own.  Since you expressed concern for efficiency in some of your comments, you'll probably want to do that in C.

Comment: Thanks for your input . Sorry if I wasn't clear in all aspects but you managed to fill in the gaps. You assumed right , I am looking into good user messaging since I am building a service that performs certain actions on behalf of the user. Given a path by the user, the system responds with: file not found, permission error, or list content if access is granted. With ```os.listdir``` I don't have a return code but I do have exceptions to manage. For the moment, the best I got is ```sudo -u $user ls $path``` but please I am open to better approaches.

Comment: Also I did not understand your 4th bullet about _traversing untraversible directories_. Could you please give an example on what you mean by that ?

Comment: @renatodamas, the mode bits that you probably think of as specifying execute permission have a different meaning for directories.  They specify permission to "traverse" directories to access the entries inside.  With only read, not traverse, access, all you can do with the directory is list its contents -- names only, not attributes.  Your example of a directory with mode 0400 is such a directory.  You need mode 0500 (dr-x------) for `ls -l` to list file attributes or to do anything at all with the files and subdirectories within, regardless of *their* modes.

Comment: @renatodamas, frame challenge: do you actually have to distinguish between the path being inaccessible and it not existing?  I mean, if there's nothing the user can do about it anyway, then that seems a bit pointless.  And if you do want to distinguish, then what's wrong with the messages that `ls` already emits?  You don't necessarily need to *parse* those; just forwarding them to the user might serve the purpose.

Comment: Ah you're right . I mentioned 400 somewhere but yea that still raises you permission denied, still need that +x for proper traversing .

Comment: You have a point there as well. I guess I can also go with that: if a user can't access certain resource might as well just throw the same error . Since this is a rest api , in that case it throws a 400 as opposed to a 403 and 404.

Answer (score 0):

An example of use.

```
for d in 1 2 3; do
    if [[ -e $d ]]; then printf  "%s exists" $d
       [[ -r $d ]] && echo " and is readable" || echo " but is not readable"
    else echo "$d does not exist"
    fi
    stat -c "%A %n" $d
done
1 exists and is readable
drwxr-xr-x 1
2 exists but is not readable
d--------- 2
3 does not exist
stat: cannot stat ‘3’: No such file or directory
```

If you absolutely have to have it in one step with differentiated exit codes, write a function. (a/b is there and has accessible permissions.)

```
$: stat -c "%A %n" ? . a/b # note there is no directory named 3
drwxr-xr-x 1
drwxr-xr-x 2
drwxr-xr-x a
drwxrwxrwt .
drwxr-xr-x a/b
$: doubletest() { if [[ -e "$1" ]]; then [[ -r "$1" ]] && return 0 || return 2; else return 1; fi; }
$: result=( "exists and is readable" "does not exist" "exists but is unreadable" ) # EDITED - apologies, these were out of order
$: for d in . a a/b 1 2 3; do doubletest $d; echo "$d ${result[$?]}"; done
. exists and is readable
a exists and is readable
a/b exists and is readable
1 exists and is readable
2 exists and is readable
3 does not exist

$: chmod 0000 a
$: for d in . a a/b 1 2 3; do doubletest $d; echo "$d ${result[$?]}"; done
. exists and is readable
a exists but is unreadable
a/b does not exist
1 exists and is readable
2 exists but is unreadable
3 does not exist
```

"does not exist" for `a/b` is because `a` does not have read permissions, so there is no way for *any* tool to know what does or does not exist in that directory short of using `root` privileges.

```
$ sudo stat -c "%A %n" ? . a/b # sudo shows a/b
drwxr-xr-x 1
drwxr-xr-x 2
d--------- a
drwxrwxrwt .
drwxr-xr-x a/b
```

In that case your problem isn't the tool, it's that the tool can't do what you are asking it to do.

Comment: If I run that against ```/tmp/root/testdir/``` (say permissions are 0400), I get ```"/tmp/root/testdir/ does not exist"```, which is not true. In that same example, if I run ```ls /tmp/root/testdir/```, I get ```"Permission denied"```, which is correct.

Comment: @renatodamas, try `ls /tmp/root/absent`.  Are you still satisfied with the accuracy of `ls`'s messaging?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes indeed so far that seems to be the most accurate messaging

Comment: `ls` will do no better if the problem is a lack of read permissions on a directory higher up the path. Are you sure the "Permission denied" message is for the directory you were targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual some more. There's also `-d` to specifically check whether the target is a directory, and a slew of other predicates to check for symlinks, device nodes, etc.

```
testthing () {
    if ! [[ -e "$1" ]]; then
        echo "$1: not found" >&2
        return 2
    elif ! [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
        echo "$1: not a directory" >&2
        return 4
    elif ! [[ -r "$1" ]]; then
        echo "$1: permission denied" >&2
        return 8
    fi
    return 0
}
```

Usage:

```
testthing "/root/no/such/directory"
```

Notice that `[[` is a Bash built-in which is somewhat more robust and versatile than the legacy `[` aka `test`.

It's hard to predict what the priorities should be, but if you want the comparisons in a different order, by all means go for it. It is unavoidable that the shell cannot correctly tell the precise status of a directory entry when it lacks read access to the parent directory. Maybe solve this from the caller by examining the existence and permissions of every entry in the path, starting from the root directory.

Comment: That fails for ```testthing /tmp/root/dir/``` with ```"not found"```. Should be ```"permission denied"``` since it can't get passed ```/tmp/root```. Similarly, running ```ls /tmp/root/dir/``` gets you a ```permission denied```.

Comment: I added a final paragraph which elaborates on this point. The question you actually asked doesn't contain very specific requirements around this.

Comment: You mention that one could iterate over the path and check for permissions individually but it's quite inefficient. In terms of priorities, both are equally relevant since you can't prioritise one property over the other. So far, a plain ```ls``` command is the desired result, it just lacks better return codes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel   0 Mar 22 12:01 can_read
---xr-x--x  1 andrew  wheel   0 Mar 22 12:01 root
drwxr-xr-x  2 andrew  wheel  64 Mar 22 13:09 sub
```

Note that permissions are by `user` for the first three, `group` for the second three and `other` or `world` for the last three.

`Permission Denied` error is from 1) Trying to read or write a file without that appropriate permission bit set for your user or group or 2) Tying to navigate to a directory without `x` set or 3) Trying to execute a file without appropriate permission.

You can test if a file is readable or not *for the user* with the `-r` test:

```
$ [[ -r root ]] && echo 'readable' || echo 'not readable'
not readable
```

So if you *only* are concerned with *user* permissions, `-r`, `-w` and `-x` test are what you are looking for.

If you want to test permissions generally, you need to use `stat`.

Here is a simple example with that same directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(can_read root sub missing)

for fn in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ -e "$fn" ]]
    then
        p=( $(stat -f "%SHp %SMp %SLp" "$fn") )
        printf "File:\t%s\nUser:\t%s\nGroup:\t%s\nWorld:\t%s\nType:\t%s\n\n" "$fn" "${p[@]}" "$(stat -f "%HT" "$fn")"
    else    
        echo "\"$fn\" does not exist" 
    fi  
done
```

Prints:

```
File:   can_read
User:   rw-
Group:  r--
World:  r--
Type:   Regular File

File:   root
User:   --x
Group:  r-x
World:  --x
Type:   Regular File

File:   sub
User:   rwx
Group:  r-x
World:  r-x
Type:   Directory

"missing" does not exist
```

Alternatively, you can grab these values directly from the `drwxr-xr-x` type data with:

```
for fn in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ -e "$fn" ]]
    then
        p=$(stat -f "%Sp" "$fn")
        typ="${p:0:1}"
        user="${p:1:3}"
        grp="${p:4:3}"
        wrld="${p:7:3}"
    else    
        echo "\"$fn\" does not exist" 
    fi  
done
```

In either case, you can then test the individual permissions with either Bash string functions, Bash regex, or get the octal equivalents and use bit masks.

Here is an example:

```
for fn in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ -e "$fn" ]]
    then
        p=$(stat -f "%Sp" "$fn")
        user="${p:1:3}"
        ty="$(stat -f "%HT" "$fn")"
        printf "%s \"$fn\" is:\n" "$ty" 
        [[ $user =~ 'r' ]] && echo "    readable" || echo "    not readable"
        [[ $user =~ 'w' ]] && echo "    writeable" || echo "    not writeable"
        [[ $user =~ 'x' ]] && echo "    executable" || echo "    not executable"
    else    
        echo "\"$fn\" does not exist" 
    fi  
done
```

Prints:

```
Regular File "can_read" is:
    readable
    writeable
    not executable
Regular File "root" is:
    not readable
    not writeable
    executable
Directory "sub" is:
    readable
    writeable
    executable
"missing" does not exist
```

(Note: `stat` tends to be platform specific. This is BSD and Linux will have different format strings...)